# POSIX description of cp -R

Tags: cp, posix

I just became really confused by the implementation of bash's `cp -R` command compared to how [POSIX words what should happen](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/cp)

Given the posix definition, I would expect `cp -R srcDir existingDestDir` to result in the **contents** of `srcDir` to be copied into the `existingDestDir`.  Instead `srcDir` gets copied into existingDestDir both in bash and csh implementations of sh.

The relevant portion of the posix cp -R definition:

> For each source_file, the following steps shall be taken:
>
> (...)
>
> 2. If source_file is of type directory, the following steps shall be taken:
>
> (...)
>
> f. The files in the directory source_file shall be copied to the directory dest_file, taking the four steps (1 to 4) listed here with the files as source_files.

I would appreciate it greatly if someone could clear this up for me.

Comment: `cp` is an external binary, so it has nothing to do with the shell. Perhaps you mean GNU's `cp` implementation?

Comment: I see - thanks a ton.  I had the incorrect impression that posix loosely translated to portability.  That and realizing cp comes from the coreutils library (from your gnu statement) helped me past my mental block.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote comments, but if either of you care enough to write an answer (albeit for a confusing question), I will mark it as correct.  I'm only a year into using linux and am still trying to grasp some fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a paragraph further up in the POSIX document:

> The third synopsis form (`cp -R [-H|-L|-P] [-fip] source_file... target`) is denoted by two or more operands where the
>   -R option is specified. The cp utility shall copy each file in the file hierarchy rooted in each source_file to a destination path named
>   as follows:
>
> - If target exists and names an existing directory, the name of the
>     corresponding destination path for each file in the file hierarchy
>     shall be the concatenation of target, a single `<slash>` character if
>     target did not end in a `<slash>`, and the pathname of the file relative
>     to the directory containing source_file.

In your case, with

```
cp -R srcDir existingDestDir
```

The "source_file" is `srcDir` and "target" is `existingDestDir`. With the paragraph, the "destination path for each file in the file hierarchy" becomes `existingDestDir/srcDir`, which explains the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing that out because I did miss that.  Still confused though because 2 -> a specifies `If the -R option was not specified, cp shall write a diagnostic message` implying `-R` is covered in the following steps.  This means that somehow your quote overrides the steps I quoted.  I'll chalk it off as being confusing (free) documentation that I am not accredited to rewrite.

Comment: @aaaaaa Not confusing. I think you are mixing up `target` with `dest_file` in the standard document: "If target exists and names an existing directory, the name of the corresponding destination path for each file in the file hierarchy shall be [target/source_file]"... "In the following description, the term `dest_file` refers to the file named by the destination path."

Comment: You're right.  I'm sorry for the confusion as I know a confused question is difficult to answer.  Re-reading the document now it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @aaaaa Now try `cp -R srcDir/ existingDestDir` and ask another question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are several points to clear up:

- [**`cp`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html) is a separate utility from [**`bash`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).  Some people may be confused by built-in commands such as **`cd`** and [**`pwd`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html) which either are or may be part of a POSIX shell.
- POSIX refers to the [series of documents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) jointly maintained by The Open Group and the IEEE, referred to as *IEEE Std 1003.1™*.
- **`bash`** is one of several shells which implement the features described in POSIX.  Most shells have some differences from the POSIX shell [**`sh`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html); the name by which the shell is run is a feature described in POSIX.
- in the section [2.14. Special Built-In Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), POSIX says

> The term *"built-in"* implies that the shell can execute the utility directly and does not need to search for it. An implementation may choose to make ***any*** utility a built-in; however, the special built-in utilities described here differ from regular built-in utilities in two respects:

So in principle **`cp`** *could* be a part of `bash` if its developers had chosen to do that.  In practice this is not done because there is no point in further complicating `bash` by adding features that can be done well *separately* from `bash`.

Next, the link mentioned in the question is *based* on POSIX, but is not *the* POSIX document.  You can see the disclaimers at the end:

> ***Portions***  of  this  text  are  reprinted  and  reproduced ...

and

> Any typographical or formatting errors that appear in this page are most  likely  to  have
>   been  introduced  during  the conversion of the source files to man page format.

But most of the manual page is copied word-for-word from POSIX.  POSIX documents are written in a quasi-legalistic style, attempting to avoid describing things in detail where its authors are aware that existing implementations differ, as well as avoid detail where they believe that implementation internal details may differ.  So what you get is a step-by-step description of actions that the programs take, and (often) omitting details which other authors would add to explain how the different steps are related.  Some of the POSIX documents provide a section for *RATIONALE*, but even those seem to be a minority.  The result is often vague, but you have to make allowances for the intent: describing common features of existing programs.

This is the specific part of the question which indicates confusion:

> Given the posix definition, I would expect *cp -R srcDir existingDestDir* to result in the contents of *srcDir* to be copied into the *existingDestDir*. Instead *srcDir* gets copied into *existingDestDir* both in bash and csh implementations of sh.

The point of the documentation is that *directories* in the source are also handled using the same iterative and recursive description as *ordinary* files.  One of the rules is outlined in the [Synopsis](http://view-source:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html#tag_20_24_02) section:

> `cp -R [-H|-L|-P] [-fip] source_file... target`

which is the third example, and the only one mentioning the `-R` option.  This is referred to later, in the [Description](http://view-source:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html#tag_20_24_03):

> The ***third*** synopsis form is denoted by two or more operands where the -R option is specified. The **`cp`** utility shall copy each file in the file hierarchy rooted in each source_file to a destination path named as follows:
>
> - If *target* exists and names ***an existing directory***, the name of the corresponding destination path for each file in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of *target*, a single `<slash>` character if *target* did not end in a `<slash>`, and the pathname of the file relative to the directory containing *source_file*.
> - If *target* does not exist and two operands are specified, the name of the corresponding destination path for *source_file* shall be *target*; the name of the corresponding destination path for all other files in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of *target*, a `<slash>` character, and the pathname of the file relative to *source_file*.

That is, your directory name is treated as a "file" in the first bulleted item, and is concatenated with the target directory's name.

Further reading:

- [cp - copy files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/cp-1.html) (Solaris)
- [cp - copy files and directories](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) (GNU coreutils)

The GNU coreutils manual page lacks detail.  You can see some of the flavor of the POSIX document in the Solaris manual page, which by the way is more clearly written:

> `/usr/bin/cp -r | -R [-H | -L | -P] [-fip@] source_dir... target`

and

> In the third synopsis form, one or more directories specified by *source_dir* are copied to the directory specified by target. Either `-r` or `-R` must be specified. For each *source_dir*, `cp` copies all files and subdirectories.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for writing all that information.  It helps my understanding greatly.  Please put a 'donate' button in your profile so I can buy you a couple beverages.